# Django DateTime format google calendar

Tags: json, django, datetime

I'm trying to creat an event in google calendar https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#add_an_event

The google api return this error:

> "Invalid value for: Invalid format: ""2016-02-01T08:00:00-00:00"""

I tried  to format correctly the date but it still don't work

Here my code:

```
 date_s = reservation.date_start.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-00:00')  
 date_e = reservation.date_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-00:00')

   date_start = json.dumps(date_s , cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)   
   date_end = json.dumps(date_e, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

   event = {
     'summary': summary,
     'location': location,
     'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
     'start': {
         'dateTime': date_start,
         'timeZone': 'Europe/Paris',
     },
     'end': {
         'dateTime': date_end,
         'timeZone': 'Europe/Paris',
     }, }

   service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)   
   event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
```

Comment: If you use `date_s` and `date_e` instead of `date_start` and `date_end` does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to json encode your dates as you already have them as strings resulted from `strftime()`, so `json.dumps()` only adds a unneeded and syntactically incorrect pair of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the `dateTime` string is a timezone offset. The problem could be that your specified offset doesn't match the timezone given in the `timeZone` property. The docs specify that you don't need to provide both, so try to use only `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` as your time format string (which should go into a variable and not be copied).